# How can I call a PLSQL function in rails, by clicking a button in a view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, plsql

I have encountered a problem in Rails, which I cannot solve.  I am pretty much a beginner, yet I must solve the following problem:

I need to build a type of dashboard page in an existing rails web app.
This dashboard page should be able to launch PLSQL procedures from an Oracle server, by providing 2 dates and clicking a button.

I tried using the `ruby-plsql` gem in `rails console`, and I am able to successfully call the wanted Oracle stored procedure.

I would like to create a view with a form to accept the date fields for the stored procedure, and then execute the stored procedure when the user clicks the submit button.  The `ruby-plsql` method should get launched on submit.  I also need to make sure that an already running procedure is not launched again, possibly by greying out the submit button, while the current procedure is running.

How can that be developed?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `ruby-plsql` and 'haml' gems to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ruby-plsql'
gem 'haml'
```

Next, you can use the Rails generator to flesh in a controller and the supporting components:

```
rails generate controller procedure execute
```

In the `config/routes`, update the `get` route to be a `post` route:

```
get 'procedure.execute'
post 'procedure/execute'
```

You can make a simple view (this example uses HAML).  Add this code to the file `app/views/procedure/execute.html.haml`:

```
%div
  %p#notice
    = "A stored procedure is currently running.  Please wait..." if @is_running

%div
  = field_set_tag "Procedure 1" do
    = form_tag procedure_execute_path, id: "form1" do
      = hidden_field_tag "proc", "stored_proc_1"
      = text_field_tag "date1", nil
      = text_field_tag "date2", nil
      = submit_tag "Execute", disabled: @is_running

%div
  = field_set_tag "Procedure 2" do
    = form_tag procedure_execute_path, id: "form2" do
      = hidden_field_tag "proc", "stored_proc_2"
      = text_field_tag "string1", nil
      = text_field_tag "number1", nil
      = submit_tag "Execute", disabled: @is_running

%div#results
  = @results if @results

%script
  $(document).on("ready", register_ajax);
  $(document).on("page:change", register_ajax);
```

Make sure to add jQuery and Unobtrusive Javascript support to `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Verify that your `config/application.rb` contains this line within the Application` class:

```
config.assets.enable = true
```

Note that the forms now determine which method will be called, and they both send the request with their distinct arguments to the same `execute` action.

The Ajax code to submit the forms asynchronously and handle the results can be added to the `/app/assets/javascripts/procedure.js` file:

```
var ajax_registered = false;

function register_ajax() {
    if (ajax_registered) {
      return;
    }

    $('#form1 input[type="submit"], #form2 input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        // First, disable all of the form buttons and put up a "running" notice
        $('form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#notice").text("A stored procedure is currently running.  Please wait...")

        var data = $(this).parent().serialize();

        // Submit the Ajax POST
        var jqxhr = $.post("/procedure/execute", data, function(data, status, xhr) {
            // Success: display the results in the #results div
            $("#results").text(data);
        }, "text")
        .fail(function(data, status, xhr) {
            // Notify the user that an error has occurred
            alert("An error has occured with the stored procedure");
        })
        .always(function(data, status, xhr) {
            // Always re-enable the submit buttons after completion
            $('form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", "");
            $("#notice").text("");
        });
    });

    ajax_registered = true;
};
```

Next, implement the `execute` action in the `ProcedureController`, which should be located at `app/controllers/procedure_controller.rb`:

```
class ProcedureController < ApplicationController
  @@running = false

  def execute
    if request.post?
      plsql.connection = OCI8.new("hr","hr","xe")
      notice = nil
      if @@running
        notice = "A stored procedure is currently running.  Try again later"
      else
        @@running = true
        proc_params = execute_params
        proc = proc_params.delete(:proc)
        case proc
        when "stored_proc_1"
          @results = plsql.my_stored_proc(proc_params)
        when "stored_proc_2"
          @results = plsql.my_other_stored_proc(proc_params)
        end
        @@running = false
      end
      if request.xhr?
        render text: @results.to_json and return
      else
        @is_running = @@running
        redirect_to procedure_execute_path, notice: notice
      end
    else
      @is_running = @@running
    end
  end

private

  def execute_params
    params.permit(:utf8, :authenticity_token, :proc, :date1, :date2, :string1, :number1)
  end
end
```

The `execute` action runs synchronously, but also uses the @@running flag to indicate that it's currently handling a request, in case another comes in from the dashboard before the currently-running proc has finished.  The `proc` hidden field in the forms is used to indicate which stored procedure to execute, and the controller dispatches according to which is chosen.

If the request came from an Ajax call, the response will be a JSON object that contains the results of the stored procedure call; otherwise, the page will be fully rendered and the result will be included.

That should be enough to get going.  It's not pretty, but the structure is there, and you can improve the `execute` method to do additional things, as well as style the view to your liking.

Comment: Wow thanks, it helped a lot!! What if I want to make multiple buttons on one page, each linked to different procedures?  And restrict that while one procedure is running, it cannot be launched again (maybe something like a bootstrap loading javascript button?), but others can be launched on the same page? (Maybe some ajax stuff..?)

Comment: To add more buttons and procedures, you'd just add the same code in again.  I'll update the answer with an example of a second procedure and button.  Making it be asynchronous isn't difficult, but making the UI resilient with asynchronous behavior is fairly complicated.  For instance, the user can refresh the page, and that shouldn't lose the state of whether a procedute is running or not; there would have to be some state storage and that would have to be synced between the controller and the UI.

Comment: I have mocked in a second form and button, with the corresponding controller logic to run the appropriate one.  I also added in basic Ajax capabilities to submit the form asynchronously and do basic UI management to prevent submitting multiple request concurrently.  This is a skeleton, but it should be something that you can build a complete solution on top of.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!
There are still some major bugs, and i don't know what the problem is.
Somehow the browser cannot go to /procedure/execute... It says "The page isn't redirecting properly". Not even the built in rails debugger shows up...
The other one is that the variable @@running is somehow true when i check it in the rails console, and because of that the following notice is shown by going the root path: "A stored procedure is currently running.  Try again later".
Thanks!

Comment: And one another thing:
You wrote that we cannot handle the UI asynchronously.
But can you please help me writing something like: if the procedure is running than if you want to close the tab, some alert pops up? And if accidentally the tab is closed, than the procedure should shut down..??
Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: I corrected the issues that you mentioned.  I also did a little improvement to the solution to make it more robust.  For the new requests for handling "close tab" and stopping the procedure, you will have to write those as new questions - they will be nearly as much work as has already been done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far!!!
It really helped a lot.
Yet somehow it still has a bug, thus the procedure cannot be called by pressing the execute button.
In the rails server log it says:
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit
Redirected to http://localhost:10524/procedure/execute
Can you please help me fixing it..?
Thanks!

Comment: @aftk7 I have updated my answer to include `utf8` and `authenticity_token` in the list of strong parameters at the end of the controller.

Comment: @aftk7 The only possible way that `commit` could be unpermitted in the log is if the form is not being submitted via Ajax.  You *must* have the jQuery scripts loaded and executed in your environment properly.  Check that jQuery and UJS are loaded properly in `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, as described in the solution, and that the `register_ajax` call is executing as expected.  This will require you to debug what is happening in your environment - the solution works as expected in my environment.