# How can I workaround heroku's 30 sec timeout when executing long PLSQL procedure in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku, timeout

In a rails web app I needed to develop a page where I can launch PLSQL procedures.
I finally developed it by this tutorial:

[How can I call a PLSQL function in rails, by clicking a button in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320310/how-can-i-call-a-plsql-function-in-rails-by-clicking-a-button-in-a-view)

But I have a huge problem. The procedures I want to launch can run for several hours. The web app is in Heroku, which has a timeout set to 30 seconds.
How can I rewrite my code in order to bypass this 30 sec timeout, and run the extremely long PLSQL procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a thing for background jobs ;) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: And what about the long polling method, where you send get requests to the server in each 25ish second, so heroku doesnt time out? I read it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses